# como obtener valores, dentro de un array de objetos usando mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Quiero implementar un buscador en el cual le paso un lista de ingredientes y que el resulado devuelto contenga todos esos ingredientes.
ejemplo

```
tomate,zanahoria
```

resulado esperado :
*sandwitch1
*sandwitch2

si agrego uno mas y este no contiene el ingrediente q no lo muestre

```
tomate,zanahoria,papa
```

resulado esperado :
*sandwitch1

la receta se almacena asi:

```
title:'hola'
ingredients: [
     { name: 'zanahoria' },
     { name: 'lechuga' }
],
```

la busqueda actualmente la hago asi

```
const res = await Recipe.find({ 'ingredients.name': { $regex: ingredient, '$options': 'i' }})
```

pero solo me sirve para leer un solo valor

intente usando $in pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo

```
{ 'ingredients.name': { $in: ['zanahora','lechuga']} },
```

espero haberme hecho entender!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal la pregunta puedes utilizar [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/):

Usando `$all` MongoDB busca que todos los elementos del array existan en el documento.

```
modelo.find({
  "ingredients.name": {
    "$all": [
      "lechuga",
      "zanahoria"
    ]
  }
})
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zK25lM05B2J)

Comment: gracias amigo, me sirvio, mejor que el que habia hecho yo que fue hacer un map sobre el array que venia del front y pasarlo por un new RegExp y despues agregando el resultado  al query $in[regex].